# Query string param is always nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

This is how I retrieve the `params[:status]` through the routes:

```
namespace :admin do
  get 'provider/status/:status', as: 'status_provider', to: 'providers#index'`
end
```

But I always get `params[:status]` return `nil`:

```
if params[:status].nil?
  providers = Provider.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
else
  providers = Provider.filter_by_params(params[:status]).order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
end
```

Here is the view:

```
<%= admin_status_provider_path("enabled") %>
```

**UPDATED**

I have also tried editing my view like this:

`<%= admin_status_provider_path(status: "enabled") %>`

```
<a href="<%= admin_status_provider_path(status: 'enabled') %>" class="btn btn-default">
  Enabled
</a>
```

But still same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your status is expecting :status to be integer so following changes should do the trick

```
namespace :admin do
  get 'provider/status/:status', as: 'status_provider', to: 'providers#index', constraints: { status: /.*/ }
end
```

this does the trick

```
Started GET "provider/status/abc" for 127.0.0.1 
Processing by ProvidersController#index as HTML
Parameters: {"status"=>"abc"}
```